# Surface area of spherical cap

Tags: calculus

Find the area of the spherical cap in the picture
[image: The surface area of the region i have shaded]

My question is when we take the derivative of the volume of a sphere with respect to r (V = $\frac{4}{3} \pi r^3$), we get the surface area (SA = 4 $\pi r^2$). In the question above, is it still correct that its surface area is the derivative of its volume with respect to r?

Thank you very much :)

Comment: Sorry, there was an ad before the video, so I switched off.

Comment: Sorry, youtube always has an ad before a vid :(

Comment: I am not sure you understood my message.

Comment: Maybe i did not :(

Comment: It is not allowed to include a video you mean?

Comment: It's not formally forbidden (AFAIK), it is bad practice.

Comment: I have edited it. It is still possible that my question is clear. Thanks :)

Comment: A figure is needed.

Comment: Sorry, i was not aware that i have enough reputation to include an image. Edited! Thanks :)

Comment: "when we take the derivative of the volume of the sphere, we get the surface area": how so ?

Comment: Should have made it clear. Edited again. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The volume of revolution of a circle equation yields a volume of $4/3\pi r^3$ with limits of integration from $-r$ to $+r$. The volume of a cap will have limits of integration from $(r-h)$ to $r$ where $h$ is the height of the cap.

It's the same for the surface area where the area of revolution yields $4\pi r^2$ for integration from $-r$ to $+r$. The surface area of the cap will be determined by applying the same limits of integration $(r-h)$ to $r$.

However for surface area, it turns out that slices of equal thickness of a sphere have the same curved surface area. So the surface area of the cap will be $h/d(4\pi r^2)$ where $h$ is the height of the cap and $d$ the diameter of the sphere.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, because the derivative on $r$ corresponds to radial increments, which follow the direction of the lateral surface of the cone.